# In-house iphone app database connection

Tags: iphone, dmz, in-house-distribution

I am going to build an in-house application within a company. I was told that the data sample is located on the DMZ network, so how can I connect to this? The main task is going to surface data and display it. I have no idea about DMZ network and is there sort of API available to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not any API for direct connection to Database(as per my knowledge)

create a local web-service, which will accessible only in DMZ network.

User those web-methods to communicate with database.

As the access of web-service is within DMZ, user will have access of data within DMZ network